# Ubuntu 18.04 cannot install Kodi - unmet dependencies (kodi-bin)

Tags: 18.04, kodi

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04. I had Kodi running fine on the previous install but now I'm unable to install it again. I'm sure I had it installed already but I haven't used it for a while and maybe uninstalled it.  Anyway I'm trying to install it now and I get the following error:

```
$ sudo apt install kodi
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 kodi : Depends: kodi-bin (< 2:17.6+dfsg1-1ubuntu1.1~) but 2:17.6+git20171114.2125-final-0xenial is to be installed
        Recommends: kodi-repository-kodi but it is not going to be installed or
                    kodi-repository
        Recommends: kodi-visualization-spectrum but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Do I need to re-install these packages? Is this something that's lingering from an old installation? If so, how do I clean it up so it's installing afresh? Thanks

ADDITIONAL INFO

```
$ apt-cache policy kodi-bin
kodi-bin:
  Installed: 2:17.6+git20171114.2125-final-0xenial
  Candidate: 2:17.6+git20171114.2125-final-0xenial
  Version table:
 *** 2:17.6+git20171114.2125-final-0xenial 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2:17.6+dfsg1-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Do you have 'universe' enabled?   https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/kodi-repository-kodi shows kodi-repository-kodi there and in universe.  As for kod-bin (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/kodi-bin) comes up with something different to what you have, so i suspect you have something unusual in your sources. Please add `apt-cache policy kodi-bin` to your question.  (*refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu if you need info on 'universe' or how to enable it*)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. Yes I have universe checked. Also, I've updated my post to include `apt-cache policy kodi-bin`. Thanks

Comment: Yes I suspect you have 'cruft' left from your xenial install that is causing a problem. The `kodi` package rule (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/kodi) for `kodi-bin` is "kodi-bin (>= 2:17.6+dfsg1-1ubuntu1)"  which isn't what your message shows. Also your xenial packaged "2:17.6+git20171114.2125-final-0xenial" on your system sorts later (g>d) than default "2:17.6+dfsg1-1ubuntu1" so `apt` will stick with your installed xenial packaged version instead of switching to the bionic one. I'd suggest `apt remove kodi` then a re-install [of kodi].  Don't use `purge` so as to not delete config files.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I also run `sudo apt autoremove` which removed the not needed kodi-bin before re-installing, which I'm guessing installed the correct version of kodi-bin coz it works now :)